# Convert moment utcOffset to Datefns or native Javascript

Tags: momentjs, utc, date-fns

I am migrating from Moment JS to date-fns. But I have hard time in converting my UTC offset Function to equivalent Date-fns Function.

Here is my Earlier Code in moment js

```
var d = new Date('2019-09-09T05:00:00Z');
var result = this.moment(d).utcOffset(-5).set({ hour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0, millisecond: 0 }).utc().format();
```

Result: **2019-09-09T05:00:00Z**

I am not able to find the equivalent function in **Datefns** or Vanilla JS for this functionality. I have tried the following code for conversion

```
function addOffsetUTC() {
    var d = new Date('2019-09-09T05:00:00Z');
    var targetTime = new Date(d);
    var timeZoneFromDB = -5 // time zone value from database
    // Get the timezone offset from local time in minutes
    var tzDifference = timeZoneFromDB * 60 - targetTime.getTimezoneOffset();
    // Convert the offset to milliseconds, add to targetTime, and make a new Date
    var offsetTime = new Date(targetTime.getTime() + tzDifference * 60 * 1000);
    // Set offset to 0
    offsetTime.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

   // Convert to UTC and then format
  return formatToUTCDateFns(toUTC(result));
} 

// Format date in UTC
formatToUTCDateFns(date: Date) {
    return format(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd') + 'T' + format(date, 'HH:mm:ss') + 'Z';
}

// Convert date to UTC
 function toUTC(date) {
    var offset = date.getTimezoneOffset();
    return Math.sign(offset) !== -1 ? addMinutes(date, offset) : subMinutes(date, Math.abs(offset));
}
```

Result  **2019-09-08T18:30:00Z.**

I think, I am lagging in adding the offset in my date. Suggestion are welcome. Thankyou